# Determine if a weekday is between two dates in R

Tags: r, date

**[Update]**

In another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842356/r-data-table-set-new-column-with-logical-value-if-a-weekday-is-between-a-date-ra), the answer from @Frank solves the problem. This question becomes duplicate of the other.

---

**[Question]**

I am writing a function in `R` to test if a weekday is in between two dates. Here is what I have, but I think the solution is not elegant. Is there a more mathematical way to do it?

```
library(data.table) ## wday is a function in this package
isDayIn <- function(weekday, date1, date2) {
  if (weekday<1 | weekday>7) stop("weekday must be an integer from 1 to 7.")
  date1 <- as.Date(date1)
  date2 <- as.Date(date2)
  output <- weekday %in% unique(wday(seq.Date(date1, date2, by=1)))
  return(output)
}

## 2015-08-02 is a Sunday and 2015-08-03 is a Monday
isDayIn(1, "2015-08-02", "2015-08-03")
> TRUE
isDayIn(7, "2015-08-02", "2015-08-03")
> FALSE
```

Note: the function `wday` starts on Sunday and ends on Saturday, so Sunday will be mapped to integer 1 and Saturday will  be mapped to integer 7.

Comment: Would you explain why the second call should be false? Day 7 (sunday, I suppose) *is* in the range provided.

Comment: You need to note the package(s) you are using. `wday` is defined in `lubridate` and `data.table` but not in base **R**.

Comment: @user2706569 `wday` starts with Sunday and ends with Saturday. You may find more information from `?data.table::wday`.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the note. I will add to the post.

Comment: @Boxuan Interesting, thank you. For users of your function isDayIn this might be confusing - without looking into the code it's not obvious that internally wday is used and the week starts with Sunday.

Comment: @user2706569 Thanks. I added some explanation about `wday`.

Comment: There is also a `wday` element in POSIXlt vectors. Unfortunately the numbering is not consistent in the various implementations. POSIX weekday numbering is 0-based, while `data.table::wday` numbering appears to be 1-based (although this is from experiment, since it is not documented in the help page.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [R data.table set new column with logical value if a weekday is between a date range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842356/r-data-table-set-new-column-with-logical-value-if-a-weekday-is-between-a-date-ra)

Answer (score 2):

Another function option using `base R`:

```
isDayIn <- function(weekday, date1, date2) {
  if (weekday<1 | weekday>7) stop("weekday must be an integer from 1 to 7.")
  weekday %in% strftime(seq(as.Date(date1), as.Date(date2), by="day"), format="%w")
}

isDayIn(1, "2015-08-02", "2015-08-03")
[1] TRUE
isDayIn(7, "2015-08-02", "2015-08-03")
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is fine. But here's a quick fix:

```
isDayIn <- function(weekday, date1, date2) {
  if (weekday<1 | weekday>7) stop("weekday must be an integer from 1 to 7.")
  require(lubridate)
  date1 <- as.Date(date1)
  date2 <- as.Date(date2)
  if (as.integer(date2 - date1) >= 7) {
    return(TRUE) # by default
  } else {
    return(weekday %in% wday(seq.Date(date1, date2, by=1)))
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good improvement because it won't extract the entire range and scan for uniques when the date range becomes large. However, I still would like to know if there is a mathematical way to deal with `weekday %in% unique(wday(seq.Date(date1, date2, by=1)))`, say modulus. Otherwise, this is a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

There already are good solutions, but none of them avoids generating a sequence of days. I tried to find a solution that just compares weekday numbers (and weeks).
It internally uses Monday as first day of the week, but the argument `startWithSunday` provides the possibility to set Sunday as day 1. An alternative would have been to switch between `%V` and `%U` in `strftime`, but this approach seems more straightforward to me.

```
isDayIn1 <- function(weekday, date1, date2, startWithSunday = FALSE) {

  if (weekday < 1 | weekday > 7) stop("weekday must be an integer from 1 to 7.")

  if(startWithSunday) {
    weekday <- max(weekday - 1, 1)
  }

  dates <- sort(as.Date(c(date1, date2)))

  if (dates[2] - dates[1] >= 7) return(TRUE)

  weeks <- strftime(dates, "%V")
  days  <- strftime(dates, "%u")

  if (weeks[1] == weeks[2]) { # Dates are in the same week.
    return(weekday >= days[1] & weekday <= days[2])
  } else { # Different weeks.
    return(weekday >= days[1] | weekday <= days[2])
  }
}
```

The function looks like a lot of code for such a small task, but most of it is just preparation; the actual work is done in the two `return` statements. The trick is to distinguish cases where the dates are within the same vs. in different weeks because this affects the comparison we ought to do.

To check if `isDayIn1` does it's job, I wrote this small wrapper function:

```
niceTests <- function(weekday, date1, date2, startWithSunday = FALSE) {

  date1 <- as.Date(date1)
  date2 <- as.Date(date2)

  fmt <- "%a, %y-%m-%d (week %V)"
  if (startWithSunday) {
    fmt <- "%a, %y-%m-%d (week %U)"
  }
  print(sprintf("Date1: %s, Date2: %s, Diff.: %d. Range contains day #%d: %s",
                strftime(date1, fmt),
                strftime(date2, fmt),
                abs(date2 - date1),
                weekday,
                as.character(isDayIn1(weekday, date1, date2, startWithSunday))
                ))
}
```

And here's the first bunch of tests. Note that `startWithSunday` defaults to `FALSE`, so here weekday `1` means Monday.

```
niceTests(7, "2015-08-02", "2015-08-03") # from question (Sunday in Su-Mo)
niceTests(6, "2015-08-02", "2015-08-03") # from question (Saturday in Su-Mo)
niceTests(1, "2015-08-02", "2015-08-09") # Full week or more.
niceTests(1, "2015-08-02", "2015-08-10") # Full week or more.

niceTests(1, "2015-08-05", "2015-08-07") # Same week. (Wednesday - Friday)
niceTests(2, "2015-08-05", "2015-08-07") # Same week.
niceTests(3, "2015-08-05", "2015-08-07") # Same week.
niceTests(4, "2015-08-05", "2015-08-07") # Same week.
niceTests(5, "2015-08-05", "2015-08-07") # Same week.
niceTests(6, "2015-08-05", "2015-08-07") # Same week.
niceTests(7, "2015-08-05", "2015-08-07") # Same week.

niceTests(1, "2015-08-08", "2015-08-11") # Across weeks. (Saturday - Tuesday)
niceTests(2, "2015-08-08", "2015-08-11") # Across weeks.
niceTests(3, "2015-08-08", "2015-08-11") # Across weeks.
niceTests(4, "2015-08-08", "2015-08-11") # Across weeks.
niceTests(5, "2015-08-08", "2015-08-11") # Across weeks.
niceTests(6, "2015-08-08", "2015-08-11") # Across weeks.
niceTests(7, "2015-08-08", "2015-08-11") # Across weeks.
```

Output:

```
[1] "Date1: Sun, 15-08-02 (week 31), Date2: Mon, 15-08-03 (week 32), Diff.: 1. Range contains day #7: TRUE"
[1] "Date1: Sun, 15-08-02 (week 31), Date2: Mon, 15-08-03 (week 32), Diff.: 1. Range contains day #6: FALSE"
[1] "Date1: Sun, 15-08-02 (week 31), Date2: Sun, 15-08-09 (week 32), Diff.: 7. Range contains day #1: TRUE"
[1] "Date1: Sun, 15-08-02 (week 31), Date2: Mon, 15-08-10 (week 33), Diff.: 8. Range contains day #1: TRUE"
[1] "Date1: Wed, 15-08-05 (week 32), Date2: Fri, 15-08-07 (week 32), Diff.: 2. Range contains day #1: FALSE"
[1] "Date1: Wed, 15-08-05 (week 32), Date2: Fri, 15-08-07 (week 32), Diff.: 2. Range contains day #2: FALSE"
[1] "Date1: Wed, 15-08-05 (week 32), Date2: Fri, 15-08-07 (week 32), Diff.: 2. Range contains day #3: TRUE"
[1] "Date1: Wed, 15-08-05 (week 32), Date2: Fri, 15-08-07 (week 32), Diff.: 2. Range contains day #4: TRUE"
[1] "Date1: Wed, 15-08-05 (week 32), Date2: Fri, 15-08-07 (week 32), Diff.: 2. Range contains day #5: TRUE"
[1] "Date1: Wed, 15-08-05 (week 32), Date2: Fri, 15-08-07 (week 32), Diff.: 2. Range contains day #6: FALSE"
[1] "Date1: Wed, 15-08-05 (week 32), Date2: Fri, 15-08-07 (week 32), Diff.: 2. Range contains day #7: FALSE"
[1] "Date1: Sat, 15-08-08 (week 32), Date2: Tue, 15-08-11 (week 33), Diff.: 3. Range contains day #1: TRUE"
[1] "Date1: Sat, 15-08-08 (week 32), Date2: Tue, 15-08-11 (week 33), Diff.: 3. Range contains day #2: TRUE"
[1] "Date1: Sat, 15-08-08 (week 32), Date2: Tue, 15-08-11 (week 33), Diff.: 3. Range contains day #3: FALSE"
[1] "Date1: Sat, 15-08-08 (week 32), Date2: Tue, 15-08-11 (week 33), Diff.: 3. Range contains day #4: FALSE"
[1] "Date1: Sat, 15-08-08 (week 32), Date2: Tue, 15-08-11 (week 33), Diff.: 3. Range contains day #5: FALSE"
[1] "Date1: Sat, 15-08-08 (week 32), Date2: Tue, 15-08-11 (week 33), Diff.: 3. Range contains day #6: TRUE"
[1] "Date1: Sat, 15-08-08 (week 32), Date2: Tue, 15-08-11 (week 33), Diff.: 3. Range contains day #7: TRUE"
```

Finally, tests for `startWidthSunday = TRUE` where day 1 is Sunday:

```
print("Now: Start with Sunday!")

niceTests(1, "2015-08-02", "2015-08-03", startWithSunday = TRUE) # from question (Sunday in Su-Mo)
niceTests(7, "2015-08-02", "2015-08-03", startWithSunday = TRUE) # from question (Saturday in Su-Mo)
niceTests(1, "2015-08-02", "2015-08-09", startWithSunday = TRUE) # Full week or more.
niceTests(1, "2015-08-02", "2015-08-10", startWithSunday = TRUE) # Full week or more.

niceTests(1, "2015-08-05", "2015-08-07", startWithSunday = TRUE) # Same week. (Wednesday - Friday)
niceTests(2, "2015-08-05", "2015-08-07", startWithSunday = TRUE) # Same week.
niceTests(3, "2015-08-05", "2015-08-07", startWithSunday = TRUE) # Same week.
niceTests(4, "2015-08-05", "2015-08-07", startWithSunday = TRUE) # Same week.
niceTests(5, "2015-08-05", "2015-08-07", startWithSunday = TRUE) # Same week.
niceTests(6, "2015-08-05", "2015-08-07", startWithSunday = TRUE) # Same week.
niceTests(7, "2015-08-05", "2015-08-07", startWithSunday = TRUE) # Same week.

niceTests(1, "2015-08-08", "2015-08-11", startWithSunday = TRUE) # Across weeks. (Saturday - Tuesday)
niceTests(2, "2015-08-08", "2015-08-11", startWithSunday = TRUE) # Across weeks.
niceTests(3, "2015-08-08", "2015-08-11", startWithSunday = TRUE) # Across weeks.
niceTests(4, "2015-08-08", "2015-08-11", startWithSunday = TRUE) # Across weeks.
niceTests(5, "2015-08-08", "2015-08-11", startWithSunday = TRUE) # Across weeks.
niceTests(6, "2015-08-08", "2015-08-11", startWithSunday = TRUE) # Across weeks.
niceTests(7, "2015-08-08", "2015-08-11", startWithSunday = TRUE) # Across weeks.
```

Output:

```
[1] "Now: Start with Sunday!"
[1] "Date1: Sun, 15-08-02 (week 31), Date2: Mon, 15-08-03 (week 31), Diff.: 1. Range contains day #1: TRUE"
[1] "Date1: Sun, 15-08-02 (week 31), Date2: Mon, 15-08-03 (week 31), Diff.: 1. Range contains day #7: FALSE"
[1] "Date1: Sun, 15-08-02 (week 31), Date2: Sun, 15-08-09 (week 32), Diff.: 7. Range contains day #1: TRUE"
[1] "Date1: Sun, 15-08-02 (week 31), Date2: Mon, 15-08-10 (week 32), Diff.: 8. Range contains day #1: TRUE"
[1] "Date1: Wed, 15-08-05 (week 31), Date2: Fri, 15-08-07 (week 31), Diff.: 2. Range contains day #1: FALSE"
[1] "Date1: Wed, 15-08-05 (week 31), Date2: Fri, 15-08-07 (week 31), Diff.: 2. Range contains day #2: FALSE"
[1] "Date1: Wed, 15-08-05 (week 31), Date2: Fri, 15-08-07 (week 31), Diff.: 2. Range contains day #3: FALSE"
[1] "Date1: Wed, 15-08-05 (week 31), Date2: Fri, 15-08-07 (week 31), Diff.: 2. Range contains day #4: TRUE"
[1] "Date1: Wed, 15-08-05 (week 31), Date2: Fri, 15-08-07 (week 31), Diff.: 2. Range contains day #5: TRUE"
[1] "Date1: Wed, 15-08-05 (week 31), Date2: Fri, 15-08-07 (week 31), Diff.: 2. Range contains day #6: TRUE"
[1] "Date1: Wed, 15-08-05 (week 31), Date2: Fri, 15-08-07 (week 31), Diff.: 2. Range contains day #7: FALSE"
[1] "Date1: Sat, 15-08-08 (week 31), Date2: Tue, 15-08-11 (week 32), Diff.: 3. Range contains day #1: TRUE"
[1] "Date1: Sat, 15-08-08 (week 31), Date2: Tue, 15-08-11 (week 32), Diff.: 3. Range contains day #2: TRUE"
[1] "Date1: Sat, 15-08-08 (week 31), Date2: Tue, 15-08-11 (week 32), Diff.: 3. Range contains day #3: TRUE"
[1] "Date1: Sat, 15-08-08 (week 31), Date2: Tue, 15-08-11 (week 32), Diff.: 3. Range contains day #4: FALSE"
[1] "Date1: Sat, 15-08-08 (week 31), Date2: Tue, 15-08-11 (week 32), Diff.: 3. Range contains day #5: FALSE"
[1] "Date1: Sat, 15-08-08 (week 31), Date2: Tue, 15-08-11 (week 32), Diff.: 3. Range contains day #6: FALSE"
[1] "Date1: Sat, 15-08-08 (week 31), Date2: Tue, 15-08-11 (week 32), Diff.: 3. Range contains day #7: TRUE"
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a vectorized version of the answer by @CL that is also slightly more general:

```r
#' Check if a weekday is within an interval
#' 
#' @param wday Day of week (integer 1-7)
#' @param from Date. Can be a vector.
#' @param to Date. Same length as `from` and must be greater than `from`.
#' @param week_start 1 = Monday. 7 = Sunday
#' 
wday_in_interval = function(wday, from, to, week_start = 1) {
  if (wday < 1 | weekday > 7) 
    stop("wday must be an integer from 1 to 7.")
  if (week_start)
    wday = 1 + (((wday - 2) + week_start ) %% 7)  # Translate wday to week_start = 1 (ISO standard)
  if (any(from > to, na.rm = TRUE))
    stop("`from` must come before `to`")
  
  # If the interval is greater than a week, it trivially contains any weekday
  over_a_week = difftime(from, to, units = "days") >= 7
  
  # Check if weekday is both smaller/greater than "from" and "to"
  days_from = as.numeric(strftime(from, "%u"))
  days_to = as.numeric(strftime(to, "%u"))
  contains_weekday = ifelse(
    strftime(from, "%V") == strftime(to, "%V"),  # Dates are in the same week?
    yes = wday >= days_from & wday <= days_to,
    no = wday >= days_from | wday <= days_to  # 
  )
  
  return(over_a_week | contains_weekday)
}
```

As an example, say we want to detect intervals in a time series that overlaps weekends. We run `wday_in_interval` for Saturday and Sunday:

```r
library(dplyr)
tibble::tibble(
  timestamp = seq(as.POSIXct("2020-09-03 0:00"), as.POSIXct("2020-09-8 12: 00"), length.out = 10),
  overlaps_saturday = wday_in_interval(6, from = lag(timestamp), to = timestamp),
  overlaps_sunday = wday_in_interval(7, from = lag(timestamp), to = timestamp),
  overlaps_weekend = overlaps_saturday | overlaps_sunday
)
```

Result:

```r
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   timestamp           overlaps_saturday overlaps_sunday overlaps_weekend
   <dttm>              <lgl>             <lgl>           <lgl>           
 1 2020-09-03 00:00:00 NA                NA              NA              
 2 2020-09-03 14:40:00 FALSE             FALSE           FALSE           
 3 2020-09-04 05:20:00 FALSE             FALSE           FALSE           
 4 2020-09-04 20:00:00 FALSE             FALSE           FALSE           
 5 2020-09-05 10:40:00 TRUE              FALSE           TRUE            
 6 2020-09-06 01:20:00 TRUE              TRUE            TRUE            
 7 2020-09-06 16:00:00 FALSE             TRUE            TRUE            
 8 2020-09-07 06:40:00 FALSE             TRUE            TRUE            
 9 2020-09-07 21:20:00 FALSE             FALSE           FALSE           
10 2020-09-08 12:00:00 FALSE             FALSE           FALSE
```

On my mid-range laptop, it processes 250.000 rows in ~3 seconds.