# R data.table set new column with logical value if a weekday is between a date range

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` object with two `date` columns, `from` and `to`. I want to create a new column to determine if a specific weekday is in between the date range.

**[Data]**

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(from=seq.Date(Sys.Date(), Sys.Date()+100, by="day"))[, to:=from+sample(10, 1), by=1:nrow(DT)][, from_wd:=wday(from)][, to_wd:=wday(to)]

> head(DT)
         from         to from_wd to_wd
1: 2015-08-06 2015-08-10       5     2
2: 2015-08-07 2015-08-10       6     2
3: 2015-08-08 2015-08-18       7     3
4: 2015-08-09 2015-08-16       1     1
5: 2015-08-10 2015-08-13       2     5
6: 2015-08-11 2015-08-13       3     5
```

**[My Approach]**

In this case, I want to add a new `boolean` column `flag`, which returns `TRUE` if Wednesday is in the range of `[from, to]`.

This is my attempt:

```
DT[, flag:=0][DT[, .I[4 %in% unique(wday(seq.Date(from, to, by="day")))], by=1:nrow(DT)][[1]], flag:=1]

> table(DT$flag)

 0  1 
21 80
```

**[Question]**

The code took some time to run, and as you can imagine, it will take more time if `nrow(DT)` gets larger.

My question is: **Is there a better way to do this?** Better in terms of speed and code readability (I believe my code is not intuitive at all).

Comment: what about answers to this problem in your previous question ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837419/determine-if-a-weekday-is-between-two-dates-in-r

Comment: how many rows there will be? I am creating multi cores solution based on one of the answers from previous post

Comment: @grubjesic roughly 10M rows.

Comment: @grubjesic I am wondering if my `.I(...)` approach is slowing things down and would like to know if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Are your `from` and `to` vectors always three days apart? The computational cost of your approach comes when `from` and `to` are far apart, so that enumeration of all the intervening values (with `seq`) on a per-row basis is costly. In the special case of a moving three-day window, there are extremely fast ways to find the answer

Comment: @Frank, not necessarily. It could be from 0 day difference to 200 days difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
next_wday <- function(d,wd=4L){
    wddiff = wd - wday(d)
    d + wddiff + (wddiff < 0L)*7L
} 


DT[, flag2 := +(next_wday(from) <= to)]

# test:
DT[,table(flag,flag2)]
#     flag2
# flag  0  1
#    0 44  0
#    1  0 57
```

The idea is that you compare `to` against the next Thursday**. The replacement line could be written a number of different ways.

**Benchmark**

The OP mentioned that `from` and `to` could be up to 200 days apart so...

```
set.seed(1)
from <- seq(as.IDate("1950-01-01"), by = "day", length = 1e6)
to   <- from + pmin(200,rpois(length(from),1))
DT   <- data.table(from,to)

system.time(DT[, flag2 := +(next_wday(from) <= to)])
#    user  system elapsed 
#    2.11    0.03    2.14

# David Arenburg's solution
system.time({
    DateDT <- DT[, {
                temp <- seq(min(from), max(to), by = "day")
                temp2 <- temp[wday(temp) == 4L]
                list(from = temp2, to = temp2)
               }
             ]
    indx <- foverlaps(DT, setkey(DateDT), nomatch = 0L, which = TRUE)$xid
    DT[, flag := 0L][indx, flag := 1L]
})  
#    user  system elapsed 
#    6.75    0.14    6.89

# check agreement
DT[,table(flag,flag2)]
#     flag2
# flag      0      1
#    0 714666      0
#    1      0 285334
```

I'm using `IDate` because it is the date format that comes with the data.table package and is (?) faster to work with. There are a couple of ways one could make the code even faster:

- First, it might be faster to restrict attention to rows where `to-from` is less than 6 (since any gap 6 or greater will have every weekday), like

  ```
  DT[,flag2:=0L][to-from < 6, flag2 := +(next_wday(from) <= to)]
  ```
- Second, because the computation only depends on one row at a time, parallelization may lead to some improvement, as illustrated in @grubjesic's answer.
- Depending on the data on one's real data, additional improvements might be found.

The OP's code isn't benchmarked here because it entails splitting the data by rows and enumerating up to 200 dates per row, which will certainly be slow.

---

** or whatever `wday` being 4 means.

Comment: What does the `+` in front of the logical comparison do?

Comment: @Chris It works the same as `as.integer`, converting the logical TRUE/FALSE into integers 1/0

Comment: @Frank I just updated the OP for better randomness in the date range.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try the `foverlaps` approach

First will create data set of all the Wednesday starting from `min(from)` and ending at `max(to)`

```
DateDT <- DT[, {
                temp <- seq(min(from), max(to), by = "day")
                temp2 <- temp[wday(temp) == 4L]
                .(from = temp2, to = temp2)
               }
             ]
```

Then run `foverlaps` and extract desired rows

```
indx <- foverlaps(DT, setkey(DateDT), nomatch = 0L, which = TRUE)$xid
```

Then a simple update by reference will do

```
DT[, flag := 0L][indx, flag := 1L]
DT[, table(flag)]
#  0  1 
# 44 57
```

Comment: I am getting this error running your code: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : could not find function "."`. Could you update your answer to `list(from = temp2, to = temp2)` as in @Frank's answer? Thanks!

Comment: You have an old version of `data.table`. Please update.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my example:

```
library(parallel)

process <- function(){


  from <- seq(as.Date("1950-01-01"), by = "day", length = 100000)
  to <- seq(as.Date("1950-01-04"), by = "day", length = 100000)

  DT <- data.frame(from,to)

  Ncores <- detectCores()

  flagList <- mclapply(1:nrow(DT),function(id){

    4 %in% strftime(seq(as.Date(DT[id,1]), as.Date(DT[id,2]), by="day"), format="%w")

  },mc.cores=Ncores)

  flag <- unlist(flagList)

  return(cbind(DT,flag))

}
```

It takes just 15 sec for 100k rows on my i7 processor. Hope this helps.

Comment: comment that it is 10M showed up. Yup now this code should probably take approx 30 min. Is that ok for you?

Comment: It's kind of slow. My code runs within .08 seconds for your data set. Franks code even faster.

Comment: I'm seeing 0.03 seconds for `system.time({setDT(DT); DT[,flag2 := +( wday(from) %in% 1:4 )]})`. I don't have parallel set up here and so can't compare the timing with that, though.